# How can you let a user change a picture in html?

Tags: html

I have an img src="example.jpg", and I also have an input type="file". I would like to know if there was a way to make the input type="file" change the img to whatever the user chooses off of his/her computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example with what you're asking, although it doesn't handle persistence, login sessions, or anything else you'll need for this to work in a production environment.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
function init() {
  var input = document.querySelector('input');
  var reader = new FileReader();

  // When the FileReader "load" event fires, update the image.
  reader.onload = function (e) {
      document.getElementById("image").src = e.target.result;
  };

  // Listen for when the input changes.
  input.addEventListener('change', onInputChange)
  function onInputChange(e) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="//placehold.it/200x200" id="image" height="200">
<input type="file">
```

Sidenote: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're getting downvotes as you're not including anything you've tried. SO is a place to get help with existing code, not to do research or write it for you.

Comment: thanks alot, that's all I needed, except what do I do with the top part of that code? I'm only familiar with html.